# Limit SQL query to days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this SQL query to make status report by day:

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 TITLE TEXT,
 STATUS INTEGER,
 LAST_UPDATED DATE,
 CREATED DATE
)
;
```

***Query:***

```
SELECT t.created,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '1' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '2' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '3' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '4' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status4
FROM ticket t
GROUP BY t.created
```

How I can limit this query to last 7 days?
Also I would like to get the results split by day. Fow example I would like to group the first dates for 24 hours, second for next 24 hours and etc.

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: What does your query produce and what do you want it to produce?

Comment: I think you have the most amount of gold badges with the least amount of reputation that i've ever seen :O

Comment: I updated the post. I want to get 7 rows of data. Each row with combined status per day.

Comment: Since created is already a date, there's nothing more that seemingly needs to be done aside from adding a where create >= 7 days ago.

Comment: Yes, it's a Date. By the way Date includes hour, munites and seconds or just the date?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR(t.created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS created_date,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '1' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status1,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '2' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status2,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '3' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status3,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN t.status = '4' THEN 1 END) as cnt_status4
FROM     ticket t
WHERE    t.created >= SYSDATE-7
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.created, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY created_date;
```

I used the oracle function for date conversion. I'm sure you'll find the corresponding one for postgresql.

Comment: Is there any solution without date conversion?

Comment: I'm not a postgresql expert but I suppose the date includes the time. In that case you need some kind of conversion that eliminates the time from the date.